# jsMind org chart not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

We're using jsMind to draw an org chart and it doesn't appear to be rending properly in the LMS I need it to even through it's working fine in a CodePen and in the StackOverflow editor, I can't seem to find the culprit.

In the LMS, all of the nodes are shown as plain text without any styling (a rounded box with a clickable icon) and are all lined up at the bottom of where the chart should be.

[image]

How can I identify the source of the issue?

```js
//jsMind
//https://github.com/hizzgdev/jsmind

let options = {
  container:'app',
  editable:false,
  theme:'asphalt',//'asbestos','wisteria','wisteria'
  support_html:true,
  view:{
       engine: 'canvas',    // engine for drawing lines between nodes in the mindmap
       hmargin:100,         // Minimum horizontal distance of the mindmap from the outer frame of the container
       vmargin:50,          // Minimum vertical distance of the mindmap from the outer frame of the container
       line_width:5,        // thickness of the mindmap line
       line_color:'#555',   // Thought mindmap line color
       line_style:'curved', // line style, straight or curved
       draggable:true,    // Drag the mind map with your mouse, when it's larger that the container
       hide_scrollbars_when_draggable:true, // Hide container scrollbars, when mind map is larger than container and draggable option is true.
       node_overflow: 'hidden' // Text overflow style in node
   },
}

let jm = jsMind.show(options,dd)

jm.collapse_all()
```

```html
<link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsmind@0.4.6/style/jsmind.css"
/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsmind@0.4.8/js/jsmind.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsmind@0.4.8/js/jsmind.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsmind@0.4.8/js/jsmind.screenshot.js"></script>

<script>
  let dd = {
    meta: {},
    format: "node_tree",
    data: {
      id: "root",
      topic: 'TEST TEXT HERE 1',
      /*"background-color": "#fff",
      "foreground-color": "#f26",*/
      children: [
        {
          id: "item1",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 2",
          direction: "left",
          children: [
            {
              id: "item1.1",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 3",
            },
            {
              id: "TEST TEXT HERE",
              topic:
                "TEST TEXT HERE Y",
              children: [
                {
                  id: "TEST TEXT HERE 4",
                  topic:
                    "TEST TEXT HERE X",
                },
                {
                  id: "item1.2.2",
                  topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 5",
                },
                {
                  id: "item1.2.3",
                  topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 6",
                },
              ],
            },
            {
              id: "item1.3",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 7",
            },
            {
              id: "TEST TEXT HERE 8",
              topic:
                "TEST TEXT HERE Z",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: "item2",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 9",
          direction: "left",
          children: [
            {
              id: "item2.1",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 10",
                children:[
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.1",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 11"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.2",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 12"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.3",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 13"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.4",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 14"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.5",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 15"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.6",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 16"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.7",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 17"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.1.8",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 18"
                    }
                ]
            },{
              id: "item2.2",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 19",
            },{
              id: "item2.3",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 20",
                children:[
                    {
                        id: "item2.3.1",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 21"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.3.2",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 22"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.3.3",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 23"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.3.4",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 24"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item2.3.5",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 25"
                    }
                ]
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: "item3",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 26",
          direction: "left",
          children: [
            {
              id: "item3.1",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 27",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "item3.1.1",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 28",
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
              id: "item3.2",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 29",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: "item4",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 30",
          direction: "left"
        },
        {
          id: "item5",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 31",
          direction: "right"
        },
        {
          id: "item6",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 32",
          direction: "right"
        },
        {
          id: "item7",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 33",
          direction: "right"
        },
        {
          id: "item8",
          topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 34",
          direction: "right",
          children: [
            {
              id: "item8.2",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 35",
                children: [
                    {
                        id: "item8.2.1",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 36"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item8.2.2",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 37"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item8.2.3",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 38"
                    },
                    {
                        id: "item8.2.4",
                        topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 39"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
              id: "item8.3",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 40",
            },
            {
              id: "item8.4",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 41",
            },
            {
              id: "item8.5",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 42",
            },
            {
              id: "item8.6",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 43",
            },
            {
              id: "item8.7",
              topic: "TEST TEXT HERE 44",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  };
</script>

<div id="app" style="width: 100%; height: 500px"></div>
```